# Where is the Jaseci session variable stored and how do I access it via the terminal?

Tags: jaseci

Whenever someone logs in to the Jaseci Server via:

`jsctl login --username --password...`

The generated token is stored locally via:

```
session["connection"]["token"] = r["token"]
session["connection"]["url"] = url
session["connection"]["headers"] = {"Authorization": "token " + r["token"]}
```

I have tried to access this locally via
`jsctl global get session`
`jsctl global get token`

But they returned

```
{
  "value": null
}
```

Meanwhile trying:
`jsctl config get LOGIN_TOKEN_TTL_HOURS`
will result in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/bin/jsctl", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(jsctl())
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click_shell/core.py", line 164, in invoke
    ret = super(Shell, self).invoke(ctx)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jaseci/jsctl/jsctl.py", line 135, in interface_api
    out = remote_api_call(kwargs, api_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jaseci/jsctl/jsctl.py", line 105, in remote_api_call
    ret = ret.json()
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/daynauth/opt/anaconda3/envs/jaseci/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am assuming that the session variable is stored in the cached database, but is there another way to access the session variable without having to make a call to the database or injecting python code into the jaseci runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I figured everything was stored in a `js.session` file (who would have thought).

The session file is a simple pickle file you can access using pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

obj = pd.read_pickle(r'js.session')

#get the token
obj['connection']['token']
```